# Simple probability problem, can't think of how to start

Tags: probability

I had this exercise in class and I can't seem to find a way to start, I did the exercises on most discrete and continuous distributions but this one confuses me.

I know it must be solved by finding P(X>=4) which is 1-p(X<4) , but i don't know how to proceed.

Text says:

In a small town every year the medium (mean) number of young people that emigrate is 6.

Determine the probability that this year will emigrate at least 4 young people.

How do i solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Medium? Do you mean median?

Comment: You don't have enough information.  You need some idea of the distribution.  Example 1: Exactly 6 emigrate every  year. Then the answer is 1.  Example 2:  Alternate years - 0 emigrate or 12 emigrate.  The answer is 0.5.

Comment: No, sorry, i mean "mean". It was translated from Italian so i forgot to translate to proper English statistics term.

Comment: I saw the result of some classmates and their result was $0.85$ . They solved by doing $1-[P(x=0)+P(x=1)..+P(x=3)]$ . I have no idea what their calculations were.

Comment: @herbsteinberg that is all the data they gave me. That's why i didn't know how to solve it but apparently some course mates did because the teacher solved it in class, which i did not attend. PS: What calculations did you make to get 1 for exactly 6 ? Maybe they did 1-(exactly 0) + (exactly 1) .. + exactly(3) ?

Comment: Odds are, this should follow a [poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).  Armed with that knowledge, can you continue?

Comment: I saw people choosing $ lambda = 6 $ , so i thought about poisson too, but isn't it supposed to be n of events in a certain amount of time ? Do i choose 6 as events and 365 as time ? So 6 in 365 ? Yes i know how to proceed with poisson, so i should do poisson 4 times ? $x=0,x=1,x=2,x=3$ with $lambda = 6 $ ?

Comment: Ok i did poisson and the result for $ P(X>=4) $ is $ 0.8487 $, so clearly this was the method. I just didn't assume it was poisson. My mistake. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: $365$ here is completely irrelevant.  The average result is $6$ people emigrate per year, and we are looking at the random variable counting the number of people who emigrate in a year... the time interval that the our average is in reference to is exactly the same as the time interval that our question is about.  If we were to have these be in reference to different time intervals, then maybe $365$ would have played a role, but not here.

Comment: My comment was simply if 6 leave every year then the probability of at least 4 is 1.  Poisson assumption is reasonable, but it has to be made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing comments above:

The [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is commonly used to model scenarios such as this where we have an average rate at which an event occurs, each event is independent of the occurrences of other such events, the number of occurrences of events is a natural number, and an effectively unbounded number of events can occur.

In reality, it is not a perfect distribution to use since it would suggest that there is a positive non-zero probability that 50 billion people emigrate from our country in a year, more than the total number of living people on the planet, but it is close enough that it makes for a good approximation.

The probability of exactly $k$ occurrences within a time-period when the average number of occurrences in the same time period is $\lambda$ will be:

$$P(X=k)=\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$

In your case, we have $\lambda=6$ and you are interested in $P(X\geq 4)$

We have

$$P(X\geq 4)=1-P(X<4)= 1 - e^{-6}\left(\frac{6^0}{0!}+\frac{6^1}{1!}+\frac{6^2}{2!}+\frac{6^3}{3!}\right)\approx 0.8488$$